# Angular 2 - Make sure one API call has made before making others

Tags: angular

On every page of my website, once the user is logged in, I get the user data.

This single API call, is the most important one in my app.

The information I get from this API call is used in many components all over my application, and I need to make sure that my template will **"wait"** for this API call before moving on and showing my application data.

This API Call is defined in a service constructor, and this is how this method look like in my service:

```
public userData;
...
    getUserData()
        {
        if (this.getToken()) {
        console.log("Getting user..");
        this.http.get('thisUser?token='+this.getToken())
          .map((res:Response) => res.json())
          .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.userData = data.user;
            },
            err => { this.checkToken(err); }
          );
        }
```

Which means that my JwtService.userData variable must get information before showing my template (I have used `*ngIf="JwtService.userData` in my components).

How I can make sure I got this data first of all?

Answer (score 2):

The question is interesting.

I don't know if my solution is going to work well because I am writing from my smartphone and I can't test my code.

You are probably using a router, so you have somewhere a `<router-output>`.

You could try to write something like this:

```
<div ngIf="(callDone | async)">
 <router-output></router-output>
</div>
```

Where `callDone` is an `Observable` that is set to `false` before the API call and set to true in the callback.

Another possibility could be to link all the components to the `Observable` `callDone`. The Angular change detector should do all the work

Answer (score 1):

It depends on architecture of you application.

You can make your application lightweight with template like `<div #child><div/>`. Implement lifecycle listener `OnInit` and do any checks you want in `ngOnInit` method, then load your main component with `DynamicComponentLoader`: `dcl.loadAsRoot(MainComponent, '#child', injector);`.